# How do I iterate through 2 CSV files and get data from one and add to the other?

Tags: python, loops, csv

I'm trying to iterate over a CSV file that has a 'master list' of names, and compare it to another CSV file that contains only the names of people who were present and made phone calls.

I'm trying to iterate over the master list and compare it to the names in the other CSV file, take the number of calls made by the person and write a new CSV file containing number of Calls if the name isn't found or if it's 0, I need that column to have 0 there.

I'm not sure if its something incredibly simple I'm overlooking, or if I am truly going about this incorrectly.

Edited for formatting.

```
import csv
import sys

masterlst = open('masterlist.csv')
comparelst = open(sys.argv[1])

masterrdr = csv.DictReader(masterlst, dialect='excel')
comparerdr = csv.DictReader(comparelst, dialect='excel')

headers = comparerdr.fieldnames

with open('callcounts.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    wrtr = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=headers, dialect='excel', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, delimiter=',', escapechar='\n')
    wrtr.writerow(dict((fn,fn) for fn in headers))
    for lines in masterrdr:
        for row in comparerdr:
            if lines['Names'] == row['Names']:
                print(lines['Names'] + ' has ' + row['Calls'] + ' calls')
                wrtr.writerow(row)
            elif lines['Names'] != row['Names']:
                row['Calls'] = ('%s' % 0)
                wrtr.writerow(row)
                print(row['Names'] + ' had 0 calls')

masterlst.close()
comparelst.close()
```

Comment: Could you please format this better?

Comment: You're trying to iterate over comparerdr for each line in masterrdr without closing and reopening it.  If the files are at all reasonable-sized, you should keep comparerdr's contents in memory.  If they're too large for that, I'd look into sorting them both (possibly at the OS level into temporary files) and taking advantage of the knowledge that they're sorted to make only one pass through each.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I should close the file at the end of the first loop and open it again in each iteration?

Comment: You should rethink your algorithm so you don't have to do that.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I will continue to research it. I'm not really sure how to approach it now.

Comment: I added a version showing how to read your compare list into memory once and then just reference it below.  That could get a lot fancier if you want to do things like allow for multiple appearances of a given name in the list or the like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help. I was able to nest another with statement inside of my outer loop, and add a variable to test whether or not the name from the master list was found in the compare list. This is my final working code.

```
import csv
import sys

masterlst = open('masterlist.csv')
comparelst = open(sys.argv[1])

masterrdr = csv.DictReader(masterlst, dialect='excel')
comparerdr = csv.DictReader(comparelst, dialect='excel')

headers = comparerdr.fieldnames

with open('callcounts.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    wrtr = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=headers, dialect='excel', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, delimiter=',', escapechar='\n')
    wrtr.writerow(dict((fn,fn) for fn in headers))
    for line in masterrdr:
        found = False
        with open(sys.argv[1]) as loopfile:
            looprdr = csv.DictReader(loopfile, dialect='excel')
            for row in looprdr:
                if row['Names'] == line['Names']:
                    line['Calls'] = row['Calls']
                    wrtr.writerow(line)
                    found = True
                    break

        if found == False:
            line['Calls'] = '0'
            wrtr.writerow(line)

masterlst.close()
comparelst.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it, assuming the file sizes do not prove to be problematic:

```
import csv
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as comparelst:
    comparerdr = csv.DictReader(comparelst, dialect='excel')
    headers = comparerdr.fieldnames
    names_and_counts = {}
    for line in comparerdr:
        names_and_counts[line['Names']] = line['Calls']
        # or, if you're sure you only want the ones with 0 calls, just use a set and only add the line['Names'] values that that line['Calls'] == '0'


with open('masterlist.csv') as masterlst:
    masterrdr = csv.DictReader(masterlst, dialect='excel')
    with open('callcounts.csv', 'w') as outfile:
        wrtr = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=headers, dialect='excel', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, delimiter=',', escapechar='\n')
        wrtr.writerow(dict((fn,fn) for fn in headers))
        # or if you're on 2.7, wrtr.writeheader()
        for line in masterrdr:
            if names_and_counts.get(line['Names']) == '0':
                 row = {'Names': line['Names'], 'Calls': '0'}
                 wrtr.writerow(row)
```

That writes just the rows with 0 calls, which is what your text description said - you could tweak it if you wanted to write something else for non-0 calls.

Comment: I am on 2.6 so unfortunately no writeheader(). I'm going to give this a shot. Thank you for the assist.

Comment: Sorry, I spaced and forgot to make a DictReader for masterlist.

Comment: Also, there are more concise and Pythonic ways to express the loops or avoid using loops altogether, but if you're struggling with the basic algorithm I think this comparatively explicit approach makes it clearer what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I didn't even notice as I was just leaving the office and was in a hurry. I ran your code exactly as you have it. I had to change masterrder to masterrdr for it to run. Unfortunately the only output in the callcounts.csv is the single row of the headers

Comment: That general approach should work - I obviously can't test it on your actual data.  I would run just the part that reads your compare csv to see if `names_and_counts` looks right, and then maybe have it report what it thinks it's getting for the names in the master file.  They do have to match up exactly - there are ways to correct for capitalization or whitespace variation if that's what you need.